No output for CAN protocol configuration on the Tiva TM4C1294ncpdt board using direct register manipulation
#include \<stdint.h\>
#include "tm4c1294ncpdt.h"

// Functions

void Config_msg_Obj(void);
void delay(unsigned int i);
void CAN_Init(void)

{
SYSCTL_RCGCCAN_R = 0x02;                // CAN Module 0 Run Mode Clock Gating Control
SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R = 0x03;               // GPIO Port B Run Mode Clock Gating Control
GPIO_PORTB_AHB_DEN_R = 0x03;            // Digital pin enable for port B pin PB0 & PB1
GPIO_PORTB_AHB_AFSEL_R = 0x03;          // GPIO Port B Alternate Function Select
GPIO_PORTB_AHB_PCTL_R |= 0x0077;        // Port B mux pin set
CAN1_CTL_R |= 0x41;                     // CAN 1 Initialization and canbit register write access enable
CAN1_BIT_R = 0x1C09;                    // Bit timing for clk 16Mhz and 100 kbs bit rate (bit time calc web - can c of bosch)
CAN1_CTL_R &= \~(1\<\<0);                  // CAN 1 intialization clear
while(CAN1_IF1CRQ_R & CAN_IF1CRQ_BUSY); // wait until CAN become ideal

}

void Config_msg_Obj(void)

{

    if((CAN1_IF1CMSK_R | 0)==0)
        CAN1_IF1CMSK_R= 0xB3;                 // command mask provides status to other function
    if((CAN1_IF1ARB2_R |0 )==0)
        CAN1_IF1ARB2_R |= (1<<15)|(1<<13)|(1<<2);
    CAN1_IF1MCTL_R |= CAN_IF1MCTL_EOB |(CAN_IF1MCTL_DLC_M & 8 );
    
    int Tx_data[8] ={0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07,0x08};
    
    CAN1_IF1DA1_R = (Tx_data[1]<<8) | Tx_data[0];
    CAN1_IF1DA2_R = (Tx_data[3]<<8) | Tx_data[2];
    CAN1_IF1DB1_R = (Tx_data[5]<<8) | Tx_data[4];
    CAN1_IF1DB2_R = (Tx_data[7]<<8) | Tx_data[6];
    
    CAN1_IF1CRQ_R |= 0x01;
    CAN1_IF1MCTL_R |= CAN_IF1MCTL_TXRQST;

}

void delay(unsigned int i)
{
while(i--);
}

int main(void)

{
CAN_Init();
delay(10000);
Config_msg_Obj();
while(1);
}


Having trouble seeing the results through DSO for configuring the CAN Protocol utilizing the direct registry and the TIVA data sheet.
No error code, however the output is not visible as pulses.
In case anything more needs to be done.
Note: Board Tiva C series - TM4C1294NCPDT
